# Запись потока видео с камеры

Tags: java, android, android-sdk

Добрый день! Возможно ли вести запись потока видео с камеры, в то время как телефон заблокирован?

Comment: Я не уверен, но скорее всего нельзя. По крайней мере, я надеюсь, что нельзя. Иначе это огромная дыра в безопасности.

Comment: @metalurgus в апп сторе есть ряд приложений которые реализуют данную функцию

Comment: А можно ссылку хоть на какое-нибудь? я бы посмотрел...

Comment: @metalurgus https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kimcy929.secretvideorecorder

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14952081/1568530
вот такой ответ нашел

Comment: @metalurgus, этот способ будет работать при заблокированом экране, но запись будет идти, пока активити находится на экране, при закрытии активити запись остановится

Comment: @NikotinN, я думаю, что надо просто докрутить немного сервис, чтобы он продолжал работать и без активити

Comment: @metalurgus, я так и сделал))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, возможно. Я запускаю сервис, который пишет видео. Вот его код:

```
public class RecorderService extends Service {

    private static final String TAG = "RecorderService";
    private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
    private static Camera mServiceCamera;
    private boolean mRecordingStatus;
    private MediaRecorder mMediaRecorder;
    private int VIDEO_DURATION = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        mRecordingStatus = false;
        mServiceCamera = Camera.open();
        WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        SurfaceView surfaceView = new SurfaceView(this);
        WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            1, 1,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
        );
        layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.START | Gravity.TOP;
        windowManager.addView(surfaceView, layoutParams);

        mSurfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("detail", MODE_PRIVATE);
        VIDEO_DURATION = sharedPreferences.getInt("duration", 1);

        super.onCreate();
        if (!mRecordingStatus) {
            startRecording();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        stopRecording();

        try {
            mServiceCamera.reconnect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mServiceCamera.release();
        mServiceCamera = null;

        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public boolean startRecording() {

        try {


            Camera.Parameters params = mServiceCamera.getParameters();
            mServiceCamera.setParameters(params);
            Camera.Parameters p = mServiceCamera.getParameters();

            final List<Camera.Size> listSize = p.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
            Camera.Size mPreviewSize = listSize.get(2);
            Log.v(TAG, "use: width = " + mPreviewSize.width
                    + " height = " + mPreviewSize.height);
            p.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
            p.setPreviewFormat(PixelFormat.YCbCr_420_SP);
            mServiceCamera.setParameters(p);

            try {
                mServiceCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mSurfaceHolder);
                mServiceCamera.startPreview();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            mServiceCamera.unlock();

            mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
            mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mServiceCamera);
            mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
            mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
            mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.DEFAULT);
            mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile("filePath");
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(640, 480);
            mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mSurfaceHolder.getSurface());

            mMediaRecorder.prepare();
            mMediaRecorder.start();
            Log.d(TAG, "Recording Started");


            mRecordingStatus = true;

            mMediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(VIDEO_DURATION * 60 * 1000);
            mMediaRecorder.setOnInfoListener(new MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener() {
                @Override
                public void onInfo(MediaRecorder mediaRecorder, int what, int extra) {
                    if (what == MediaRecorder.MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_DURATION_REACHED) {
                        stopRecording();
                        startRecording();
                    }
                }
            });

            return true;
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void stopRecording() {
        if (mRecordingStatus) {
            mRecordingStatus = false;
            try {
                mMediaRecorder.stop();
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "Recording Stopped");
            mMediaRecorder.reset();

            mServiceCamera.stopPreview();
            mMediaRecorder.release();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: видео пишется и при заблокирован экране и при свернутом приложении.

Comment: Я так понимаю мне необходимо просто дергать данный сервис.